# implement of Slider Revolution in my ASP.NET webforms application

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, slider, revolution-slider

I have an ASP.NET webforms application and I want to add the Slider Revolution plugin to my project.
I've added js and css files, but it doesn't work and all elements are hidden.

can anyone help me?

Comment: salam aghaye shariati in slider ro tunestin dorost konin?

Comment: @FatemehEbrahimiNik Yes, I did. but I can't remember how after 5 years ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem in asp.net when I had created a Master.page and User Controls (.ascx) for the header and the footer to appear on all content pages.

What I had forgot was to include in the end of "Footer.ascx" the following script:

`<script src="javascripts/app.js"></script>`

The particular Slider on the content page (.aspx) did not get initiated because this script was not in the footer.